# Prove that the group $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

Knowing that for $n \geq 2$, $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z}) = \big\{ A \in \mathrm{M}_{n,n}(\mathbb{Z}) \mid \det(A) \in \{ 1, −1 \} \big\}$ is a group with respect to matrix multiplication, prove that for every integer $n \geq 2$ the group $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated.

If I prove that  $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ has finite subgroups does that mean it has a finite set of generators so that it is finitely generated?

Comment: Not every subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ is finite.

Comment: Well...then where should I to start?

Comment: Maybe I should find the generator of it? But I cannot either find a good way to generate GL(n,Z).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98308/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-generate-mathrmgln-mathbb-z and  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181366/minimal-number-of-generators-for-gln-mathbbz.

Answer (score 3):

It is known, that for any Euclidean ring $R$ that $GL_n(R)$ is generated by the elementary matrices (proved via [Gaussian elimination](https://www.math.ru.nl/~bosma/onderwijs/voorjaar07/compalg5.pdf)). For $\mathbb{Z}$ there are finitely many of them (as there are finitely many invertible elements)

Comment: The key here is the Hermite normal form. Or the Smith normal form.